# Select a value by the latest dateTime value in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have table in SQL Server as below. Table Name: LANDS

```
Land_ID   UID             DM_DATE              DEL_REASON
   1       5     2013-05-21 20:31:53.773        Reason1
   1       1     2013-05-21 20:45:21.610        Reason2
   1       1     2013-05-21 20:45:27.613        Reason3
```

**I want to get the DEL_REASON for the latest DM_DATE (get the value of reasons for the last entered date), means (Reason3).**

I wrote this select statement, but it gives me this error `"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'"`

```
select [DEL_REASON] from [LANDS] where [Land_ID]='1' AND [UID] ='1' AND MAX([DM_DATE])
```

Can someone help.

Comment: And what if you have two entries with the exact same DM_DATE value but different DEL_REASON values?

Comment: if DM_DATE is unique you can do `select del_reason from lands where dm_date = select max(dm_date) from del_reason`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I do this getting the max date in another query and joining on itself:

```
select l.del_reason
from lands l
    join (
        select max(dm_date) maxdm_date, land_id, uid
        from lands
        group by land_id, uid
    ) l2 on l.land_id = l2.land_id 
            and l.uid = l2.uid 
            and l.dm_date = l2.maxdm_date
where l.land_id = 1 and l.uid = 1
```

EDIT -- As @AaronBertrand suggests, another alternative approach is to use the analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function since you are using SQL Server 2008.  This will yield a much better performance than using `MAX` as there will be fewer logical reads.  Review the execution plan of both queries and you will see that the query cost will be much lower using the analytic function, especially as the table increases in size.

```
select del_reason
from (
    select del_reason, land_id, uid, 
        row_number() over (partition by land_id, uid order by dm_date desc) rn
    from lands
) l
where l.land_id = 1 and 
    l.uid = 1 and
    l.rn = 1
```

Or perhaps even simpler perhaps:

```
select del_reason
from (
    select del_reason, 
        row_number() over (order by dm_date desc) rn
    from lands
    where land_id = 1 and uid = 1
) l
where l.rn = 1
```

Comment: Why not use ROW_NUMBER()? Should be much more efficient than this self-join, which will extrapolate reads as the table gets larger. That is if he wants a row per land_id and/or uid.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- how about the edit?  I agree, it makes it easier since OP is using SQL Server 2008.  Could get a little easier without the partitioning by as well if OP wants to include where criteria in subquery.

Comment: +1 that's better but IMHO you should point out potential performance issues with the first approach. I've experienced that it does not scale well at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- yeah, old habits with other RDBMS and earlier versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/599c4/1)**

```
select TOP 1 [DEL_REASON] 
from [LANDS] 
where [Land_ID]='1' 
AND [UID] ='1' 
ORDER BY [DM_DATE] DESC
```

Result:

```
| DEL_REASON |
--------------
|    Reason3 |
```

Comment: Yep, this works for me. But a question if I want to do it for MAX(), then how to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use common table expressions for this, to eliminate the subquery.

```
with max_date (land_id,uid,max_date)
as
(
    select land_id, uid, max(dm_date)
    from LANDS
    group by land_id,uid
)

select del_reason
from LANDS
inner join max_date
on LANDS.land_id = max_date.land_id
and LANDS.uid = max_date.uid
and LANDS.dm_date = max_date.max_date
```

Answer (score -1):

1st

```
select [DEL_REASON] from [LANDS] where [Land_ID]='1' AND [UID] ='1' AND MIN([DM_DATE])
```

2nd

> I wrote this select statement, but it gives me this error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'"

Answer this is so because your [UID] datatype , might have been declared in boolean
Check the database and if [UID] is in boolean change it to int

Hope this help you